# SCCM HKCU Detection Issue

Tags: powershell, sccm

I am deploying a package install via SCCM however I have the detection method to run the following powershell script to detect a HKCU key for whoever is currently logged on. SCCM installs the app as 'SYSTEM' account and I have not chosen to 'install for user' as this prompts our users with a UAC dialog box which i am trying to avoid.

Even though it seems like the following code has worked, when i manually alter the registry key to something other than whats specified, Software Center still shows the app as 'installed' even though in theory it shouldnt as the key has been manually amended.

What am i doing wrong here?

```
$key = 'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\MCF\Kofax'
$valueName = 'Cert'
$valueData = '1.0' 

if ((Get-ItemPropertyValue $key $valueName) -eq $valueData) {
  "installed"
} else {
  "NOT installed"
}
```

Comment: What makes you think it pulls it from that location? Have you tried to query the CIM properties, and/or altering them from there?

Comment: what do you mean? I know it pulls from that location because i have pointed it to the exact registry path i want it to query

Answer (score 0):

You can"t have an output if the software is NOT found. Every output in a detection via PowerShell counts as "Software detected".

Just delete "NOT Installed" from your script and it should work.

Comment: i have done what you have asked however the app no longer appears in software center. When i revert back to the powershell detection code i originally had, the app reappears on software center. I dont understand a detection method would hide the application in software center?

Comment: Not, the detection method just checks if the application is installed or not. Do you have any "requiremets" set?